# When I change templates in Netbeans, why doesn't anything happen?

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

I want to modify the "Java class" template, so that the class javadoc comment includes more than just the author. In Netbeans 6.8., I go to Tools > Templates > Java > Java Class, and modify the template. However, nothing seems to change. I tried restarting Netbeans, just in case, but the old template is still used.

How do I get Netbeans to recognize changes to the template for Java Classes?

Comment: Since folks are reporting that it works for them, you may need to provide more details about: what os you are on; where is NB installed; where is your userdir; which New file that you created that was incorrect; etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was putting it off, but it seems to work. Changes to a template only affect `New` files. Be sure you aren't editing one template and instantiating another.